# Como consumir una API por json con PHP

Tags: php, json, api

tengo una consulta que parece tal vez algo simple, pero buscando por la web no pude dar con la respuesta.

Resulta que tengo una api con su documentación, que muestra cuales son los parametros que acepta via Json, pero no tengo bien en claro como hacer uso de esta Api desde mi codigo Php.

Por favor si alguien tiene un ejemplo preciso sera de gran ayuda!

Aquí esta la documentación de la API: https://messaging-api.readme.io/v1.0/reference#simple-textual-message

Desde ya, muchas gracias!

Comment: En la documentación te ponen [un ejemplo de uso con PHP](https://messaging-api.readme.io/v1.0/reference#tab3)... ¿ya lo probaste con las credenciales que tienes de la API?  Prueba con eso y si no funciona entonces edita la pregunta poniendo el código y el error que recibes.

Answer (score 1):

Puedes utilizar esta libreria https://github.com/rmccue/Requests

Una vez la tengas instalada o instanciada en tu proyecto podrás hacer lo siguiente:

```
Requests::register_autoloader();

$data_to_send = json_encode(array("apikey"=>"theapikey","text"=>"Hola soy un mensaje...")));**
```

Dentro del array irian todos los parametros que quieras mandar.

Una vez lo tengas definido ejecutas una request en el metodo http que quieras , aca te pongo un ejemplo.

```
$request = Requests::post('endpinturl', array('content-type'=>'application/json'), $data_to_send);**
```

Una vez realizada la request podras consultar la respuesta con print_r($request->body).